# jQuery hide nextall element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me How can I hide all elements that are located after 3 elements ?

```js
$('.pagination_number').eq(3).nextAll('.pagination_number').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="4">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="5">5</a></li>
```

Comment: do you mean hide all elements after the third element?

Comment: `$('.pagination_number:gt(2)').parent().hide()`.

Comment: @AyoK Yes. I want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

tyr this script to hide more than 3 elements . to remove dot change sleector to `li`

```js
$('  .pagination_number:gt(2)  ').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="4">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="5">5</a></li>
```

with tag `li`

```js
$('li:gt(2)  ').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="4">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="5">5</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the class `pagination_number`, this will return an array of elements with class `pagination_number`. loop through the array from the third element, then select the parent and hide.

**Updated Snippet:**

```js
var lists = $('.pagination_number');
//index to start hiding your elements from
var indexTostartHide = 3;

for(var i = indexTostartHide; i<lists.length; i++){
  lists.eq(i).parent().hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="4">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="5">5</a></li>
```